# Invalid rpc error and setup lightnode bsc

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, light-clients

My application needs to read all transactions of a block every time a new block is created. the problem is that such a large number of requests will fail(Invalid RPC json). Can I create a node for my application to request to avoid the overload error? I've looked for documentation on how to run a bsc lightnode but can't seem to, so is there a way to run a node that starts recording only the current block without syncing the previous blocks. thanks everyone.